# How to prove $AB$ is a diagonalizable matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a positive definite matrix, $B$ an Hermitian matrix. How to prove $AB$ is a diagonalizable matrix?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$AB$ is similar to $A^{-1/2}(AB)A^{1/2}=A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}$ which is Hermitian and thus diagonalizable. A matrix which is similar to a diagonalizable matrix is diagonalizable as well.

Comment: Just because a matrix is symmetric doesn't mean it is diagonalizable.

Comment: Ok, I missed that it is complex Hermitian (not real symmetric). Every real symmetric and complex Hermitian matrix is diagonalizable.

Comment: You're right I just wanted to point out just so OP doesn't get the wrong impression. I knew what you meant but she might not.

Comment: how do you know that A^1/2 B A^1/2 is hermitian?

Comment: @ajl123 both $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian.