# Is this matrix take the form $M^{-1}A$ diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-element-method

Is this matrix $M^{-1}A$ which often appears in finite element method for parabolic PDEs diagonalizable? Both are N-by-N and tridiagonal and diagonal dominant matrices.

$$M=\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 1 &  &  &  \\ 1 & 4 & 1 &  &  \\  & 1 & \ddots  & \ddots  &  \\  &  & \ddots  & 4 & 1 \\  &  &  & 1 & 4 \end{pmatrix}$$

$$A=\begin{pmatrix} - & + &  &  &  \\ + & - & + &  &  \\  & + & \ddots  & \ddots  &  \\  &  & \ddots  & - & + \\  &  &  & + & - \end{pmatrix}$$

With experiments with randomly generated matrix A, it seems that it's right. But can anyone give some clues for rigorous proof?

Thanks!

Comment: Is $A$ symmetric?

Comment: $M^{-1}A$ is diagonalizable when $A$ is symmetric, So my question is if this conclusion hold for general diagonally dominant matrix taking the above form.

Comment: You might find your answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/511213/how-to-prove-ab-is-a-diagonalizable-matrix).

Comment: @AlgebraicPavel Thank you...In fact I wonder if this is also true when $A$ is not symmetric,

Comment: I've tried to make a sort of answer for that case too.

Answer (score 0):

Since $M$ is SPD and $A$ is symmetric, $M$ has an SPD square root $M^{1/2}$ (with the SPD inverse $M^{-1/2}$). The matrix $M^{-1}A$ is similar to $M^{1/2}(M^{-1}A)M^{-1/2}=M^{-1/2}AM^{-1/2}$, which (since $A$ and $M^{-1/2}$ are symmetric) is symmetric and hence diagonalizable.

The case when $A$ is not symmetric is tricky. For example, $A$ being diagonalizable is not a sufficient condition for $M^{-1}A$ being diagonalizable (and vice versa). For example,
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}4&1\\1&4\end{bmatrix},
\quad
A=\begin{bmatrix}16&8\\4&17\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Here $M$ is SPD and $A$ is diagonalizable (in addition, $A$ is diagonally dominant). However,
$$
M^{-1}A=\begin{bmatrix}4 & 1\\ 0 & 4\end{bmatrix}
$$ 
is not diagonalizable.

Note that since the set of diagonalizable matrices is a dense subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ (w.r.t. any norm), a random matrix (without a special structure) is almost sure to be diagonalizable.

Comment: Thank you...It's quite clever,but in this counterexample,$A$ is not in the tridiagonal form in the original question, right?

Comment: All $2\times 2$ matrices are tridiagonal.

Comment: But it's not with all diagonal entries negative?

Comment: If the products of the opposite off-diagonal entries of $A$ are positive, then $A$ is [similar to a symmetric (tridiagonal) matrix](http://books.google.fr/books?id=IZvkFET3LlwC&lpg=PP1&dq=matrices%20quadrature&hl=cs&pg=PA24#v=onepage&q&f=false). However, I'm not sure now how does this help here.